# Angular logging click 2 times on one click

Tags: forms, angular, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to create 2 buttons, power on and power off, that have click events for their respected statuses. I have them as radio buttons, but i wanted them to be submitted on click without a submit button, like a switch. So i decide to just have them as pseudo forms, and add click listeners to each to release the event data.

I was testing this by logging the click, and when i click on, the console logs 2 clicks, despite clicking it once.

component snippet

```
onClick(data: any) {
        console.log('click');
}
```

html snippet

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label
                    class="power-toggle on btn btn-lg btn-success"
                    (click)="onClick($event)"
                >
                    <input type="radio" name="power" value="power-on" autocomplete="off">
                        ON
                </label>
                <label
                    class="power-toggle off btn btn-lg btn-danger active"
                    (click)="onClick('off')"    
                >
                    <input type="radio" name="power" value="power-off" autocomplete="off" checked>
                        OFF
                </label>
            </div>
```

why is this happening? how can i fix it? is there a way to submit the radio value as is without a submit button or turning the button into a submit button?

Comment: If they are a group of radio buttons ... doesn't turning one off turn the other on and visa versa? If that is the case, you'll get the onClick from both of them. If you want them to be one value, could you bind them to the same property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the click function to the input and not the label.

Please find the plunker example here : https://plnkr.co/edit/Fmhs8xQupAynJfmwtk5y

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label
                    class="power-toggle on btn btn-lg btn-success"

                >
                    <input (click)="onClick($event)" type="radio" name="power" value="power-on" autocomplete="off">
                        ON
                </label>

                <label
                    class="power-toggle off btn btn-lg btn-danger active"

                >
                    <input (click)="onClick('off')"  type="radio" name="power" value="power-off" autocomplete="off" checked>
                        OFF
                </label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that worked. any ideas on how to submit this like a form without a submit button? so the the radio submits it's value on click, like a normal form, instead of doing a click function? or is the click function the simplest way